# Learning Java Swing: Understanding frame redrawing/refreshing

Tags: swing, event-handling

I am just beginning to understand Java Swing. I wanted to quickly code something to understand the event handling and wrote the following code. As you can see that the event handling works okay as the "inside mouseclicked method!" message is printed to the console but I cannot 'see' the label added to the frame,the label in this case is whatever I type in the text box, the string I entered is not visible, until I resize the frame by pulling it's corner! This is a little strange for me as a beginner. Can someone please explain what's happening?

Here is the code:

```
package com.learning.java.gui;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputListener;

    public class FirstGUIFrame extends JFrame{
        private static FirstGUIFrame firstgui=null;

        FirstGUIFrame(){
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);
            setSize(600,400);
        }

        public static FirstGUIFrame getFrameObj(){
            return firstgui;
        }


        public static void main(String ar[]){       
            firstgui = new FirstGUIFrame();
            JLabel name = new JLabel("UserName:");
            TextField textfield = new TextField("enter you name here", 15);
            JButton jbutton = new JButton("Enter");
            jbutton.addMouseListener(new buttonListener());

            firstgui.add(name);
            firstgui.add(textfield);
            firstgui.getContentPane().add(jbutton);

        }
    }


    class buttonListener implements MouseInputListener{
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            FirstGUIFrame frame = FirstGUIFrame.getFrameObj();
            System.out.println("inside mouseclicked method!");
            frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Clicked!!"));    
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a component to a visible GUI the code should be:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

The revalidate() makes sure the layout manager is invoke so a size/location is set for your new component. The repaint() makes sure all components are repainted on the panel.